# Hide a string in a txt file?

Tags: files, encryption

I plan to hide `bulm+mNtdeWE/P7ccZzg=w=n`. Where ? In a txt file, but not in the content, nor in the extra attributes.

I did it on `OSX 10+` and `Windows 7`, with respective processes. Now I am trying this by using Ubuntu.

Maybe naive, I think of hiding in into the file bits, somewhere outside of the content part and the attributes part. But I dont manage to find any doc' about file `Unix` skeleton nor Ubuntu software...

How can I hide text into a text file this way?

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with this?

Comment: Are you looking for something comparable to ADS (Alternate Data Streams) on NTFS file systems? You can access them under Windows as `file.txt:hidden_ads`, where `file.txt` is the visible file and `hidden_ads` the invisible attached ADS. This does not exist for ext4 file systems but a similar thing: **Extended File Attributes** or `xattr`, which are limited to about 4kB per stream though, depending on the implementation. See [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#Linux). Is that what you mean?

Comment: @ByteCommander That s exactly what I did on Windows. But I aim the thing to be OS-FS-independant. Ony file.

Comment: @muru Kind of Steganography. Data put in the file, hidden.

Comment: @3pic if it's steganography, why not just disperse it in the content?

Comment: @muru I aim to do both, disperse in content is done. But it is quite weak for text files.

Comment: But you can't use steganography with txt files as container! It will be visible. You can only hide things in data that may and naturally do contain distortions, such as photos, videos or audio files.

Comment: File metadata is quite filesystem dependent, you can't really hope to keep it across filesystems in a meaningful way. Stick to content.

Comment: @muru that's my conclusion, too, after some search sessions. Go for content. Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander I'm not sure. These are all ASCII characters. A simple way would be to map them to Unicode characters, with some sort of bit shifting, perhaps. Making the content meaningful, of course, is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

[SNOW](http://www.darkside.com.au/snow/) (package `stegsnow`) can do this by appending whitespace to the end of lines.